# Google speech API internal server error -83104

Tags: google-speech-api

I am newly touching [Google speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/) and trying to make the [official Node.js demo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/speech) work.

But when I using a .flac file (record from my phone and converted) to test the demo, I got this error from Google speech API server:

```
Got audio file!
Analyzing speech...
{ Error: Aborted: internal server error -83104
    at Request._callback (~/work/demo/nodejs-docs-samples/speech/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/transporters.js:85:15)
    at Request.self.callback (~/work/demo/nodejs-docs-samples/speech/node_modules/request/request.js:198:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (~/work/demo/nodejs-docs-samples/speech/node_modules/request/request.js:1057:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (~/work/demo/nodejs-docs-samples/speech/node_modules/request/request.js:1003:12)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
  code: 409,
  errors: 
   [ { message: 'Aborted: internal server error -83104',
       domain: 'global',
       reason: 'aborted' } ] }
```

And neither the audio file is uploaded to Google cloud storage as a `gs://` prefixed URI nor base64 string content works in PostMan/curl. Always get `internal server error -83104`.

I don't know what the meaning this error code stand for, anyone could help?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found in the [official trouble-shooting page](https://cloud.google.com/speech/support) it says only support for 1 channel flac file. but the file I was using is 2 channels record from my phone.

After convert the 2 channels audio file to 1 channel, it works fine.

Comment: If you want to know how to convert to mono channel, here is the solution, with sample Node.js: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42214309/1161370