# Google transcription fails for medium length files on console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

I am trying to generate a transcription from Google's speech-to-text service from sample audio files. I tried some 1 min audio files, and it generated good transcription. But when I tied 30 mins or 1-hour files from some random podcast for testing, it failed 100% of the time. These are my configuration -

```
Language code: en-US
Transcription model: Latest Long
Word confidence: Enabled
Automatic punctuation: Enabled
Speaker diarization: Enabled
Min speaker count: 2
Max speaker count: 4
```

I will also attach some screenshots. Any solution, suggestion or comment will help. Thanks[image: Traanscrition list status][image: fail message]

Comment: Does this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39093296/) help you?